# Searching an ArrayList

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I currently have 3 classes, a main class containing a GUI, and the `fnameTxtField`, a customer class containing the data, and a `customerList` class which gathers the data from the customer class, and puts it into an array list.

Comment: The question does not make sense to me.

Comment: What is `searchCustomer(fnameTxtField.getText)` and how do you know `customer.returnID()` is the number of elements in `search`? Are you sure `fnameTxtField.getText` should not be `fnameTxtField.getText()` ? Are you sure it even compiles?

Comment: You haven't really described the problem at all, or explained what `returnID()` is meant to do. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. I'd also suggest that you start following Java naming conventions.

Comment: Can you please rewrite it with, like, one quarter of the words?

Comment: if it doesn't compile show us the error you are getting

Comment: Syntax error on token ".", ... expected

I'm sorry if my first question wasn't so clear,

returnID returns an integer from the customer class

every record in the arraylist has an ID

Comment: so `returnID` gives the total number of records.?

Comment: This sounds like homework too me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are using `fnameTxtField.getText`, Java is expecting you to *declare a method parameter* (kind of like declaring a variable).  A parameter is information that your method is *told* about for one particular execution, instead of having to find out on its own.

So you are right in thinking you want something like this:

```
public void searchCustomer(String familyName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < customer.returnID(); i++) {
        customer search = search.get(i);
        if (search.returnFamilyName().equals(familyName)) {
            System.out.println("Index: " + i);            
            //removed  return i;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Then at the point of *invocation* (method call) specify that you want to use the value in your text field:

```
//...
searchCustomer(fnameTxtField.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix: Refactor your method to have the following signature `public void searchCustomer(String text) { ... }` and call it with 
`searchCustome(fnameTxtField.getText())`.
Then you could use the variable "text" in your method, so the line

`if (search.returnFamilyName().equals(fnameTxtField.getText))`

changes to

`if (search.returnFamilyName().equals(text))`

(Or don't have any parameters at all and add the [probably] missing parentheses to `fnameTxtField.getText`)